# Dot Product Laws: $a\cdot b = ||(a \cdot r) - (b \cdot r)||$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that given some n-dimensional vector $r$; and two other n-dimensional vectors say $a,b$.

That $a\cdot b = ||(a \cdot r) - (b \cdot r)||$. I'm a graduate at a job and if this is true then this would be incredible!

The work so far, I tried to just think of a proof left to right, but I can't seem to get it working out. I'll be active and try work it out as I post this.

I hope this is allowed; but to extend the questions, if you could choose assumptions about relevant vectors, is there any way this could be true?

Comment: $||(a \cdot r) - (b \cdot r)|| = ||r \cdot (a - b)||$

Comment: Some context as to why this is useful (or something similar) is that my final need is $a \cdot b$ and I want to try introduce a reference vector to do the same thing.

Comment: So somehow use a reference vector to seperate this direct dot product calc. It's kinda a long story and if you need an elaboration I can spill a little later tonight, but it basically would be really useful.

Comment: Clearly $a\cdot b\neq|a\cdot r-b\cdot r|$, take for example $a=b=e_1=(1,0,...,0)$ and $r=e_2$, then $a\cdot b=1$ but the RHS is $0$. The statement in your first comment is true.

Comment: Spamming the comments section isn't going to help matters. Please edit your stuff into the OP of the post. >_>

Answer (score 4):

No.  Take $n=1$ and $a,b,r=1$.  You have that the dot product in $\Bbb R^1$ is the same as usual multiplication and the norm is the same as the usual absolute value, but $1\cdot 1$ is clearly not equal to $|1 - 1|$

Comment: Is there any situation it does work? Say using $n = (1 \sqrt 2, 1 \sqrt 2)$

Comment: @Florian Suess what is your $n$ supposed to be there?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would write it a bit differently:

> $$a\cdot b = \Big|(a \cdot r) - (b \cdot r)\Big|$$

Notice that $a \cdot r$ and $b \cdot r$ are scalars, not vectors. So their difference is a scalar, and so we should use single lines (absolute value) instead of double lines (which denote the norm of a vector, usually not a scalar).

Secondly, this is not usually true. Others have already given counterexamples, but another case worth considering is when $a = b$. Then $a \cdot b = \|a\|^2$, but $a \cdot r = b \cdot r$, so $\left| (a \cdot r) - (b \cdot r) \right| = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Dot product distributes across vector addition, so $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf r - \mathbf b \cdot \mathbf r = (\mathbf a - \mathbf b) \cdot  \mathbf r$ even without the norm signs.